# table aliasing in sqlite but not mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have moved the exact same database tables from MYSQL to SQLITE. The following query works in MYSQL

```
select castkey, frname, lname, rolename from patrons, cast 
WHERE (patrons.personkey=cast.personkey) and cast.showkey=8 
order by cast.roletype, sex desc
```

but in SQLITE I get an "error near '.'" syntax error.  With table aliasing of cast to c, the query works fine:

```
select castkey, frname, lname, rolename from patrons, cast as c
WHERE (patrons.personkey=c.personkey) and c.showkey=8 
order by c.roletype, sex desc
```

What is the reason that Sqlite doesn't like the first version of the query?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the old comma-join syntax. (It was superseded in 1992).

Try this

```sql
select castkey, frname, lname, rolename 
  FROM patrons
  JOIN cast ON patrons.personkey=cast.personkey
 WHERE cast.showkey=8 
 ORDER BY cast.roletype, sex desc
```

and your alias situation should clear up.

Comment: The real error was using 'cast' as a table name when it is also a keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can find `CAST` in the list of [SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).
Although SQLite allows the use of most keywords as identifiers, you should avoid using them, or if you use them enclose them inside backticks, square brackets or double quotes.
This works:

```
select castkey, frname, lname, rolename 
from patrons, cast 
where (patrons.personkey=`cast`.personkey) and `cast`.showkey=8 
order by `cast`.roletype, sex desc
```

but you should also use proper join syntax:

```
select castkey, frname, lname, rolename 
from patrons join cast 
on (patrons.personkey=`cast`.personkey) 
where `cast`.showkey=8 
order by `cast`.roletype, sex desc
```